# Android device monitor crashing -- possibly due to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

Here's an odd issue I can't seem to find any information on.

I'm working on an Android app with a friend who uses Eclipse -- I use Ant and the Android command-line tools. Sometimes when I checkout code that was written by him and the project.properties file gets pulled into my local workspace, I'll have to change the path to the libraries back to where they're at on my machine, as it gets automatically set for him via Eclipse. This may be of use to know in light of what just started happening when I try to launch 'monitor' as I've always done; I get this error dialog box that pops up and says: An error has occurred, please see the logfile: /home/user/.android/monitor-workspace/.metadata/.log

So I did. It was, after I'd tried to launch monitor several times to no avail, a really long logcat-like file of Java traces. I cleared them out, thinking that perhaps it had run over its own max size for internal monitor data, but that didn't stop it crashing. A new set of errors just gets appended.

This is the first time this has ever happened, and unlike essentially every other Android problem I've had, I can't seem to find any existing information on it. The device monitor now seems to want to be integrated into Eclipse. I don't use Eclipse so I'm not sure how the monitor runs within it, or whether I'm correct in assuming that some configuration file somewhere needs to have a line changed (or whatever).

Here's the content of the logfile:
http://pastebin.com/JitCWrGg

Could anyone lend a word of advice?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running `android update project`? This should also automatically fix your android path issues in project.properties, However as a note: you should not have the sdk path in project.properties, it should be in local.properties (which you don't check in to source control)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I updated the project as per your suggestion, but unfortunately the monitor still crashes in the same fashion. And in project.properties, when I said a path to the libraries, I meant external resources like ActionBarSherlock -- nothing that came bundled with the SDK.

Comment: Ah, well that makes more sense.  I will look at the Log in a few minutes (while I'm in a meeting), and will get back to you

Comment: Are you launching DDMS from Eclipse or from terminal/CMD?

Comment: From the terminal, with 'monitor'.

Comment: Well, without knowing the implementation of DDMS I can't say what the problem is either.  I would recommend making sure you have the most up-to-date version of the platform tools, ddms, etc.  If it still persists, I would remove and re-install the Android SDK.  As a note: you are seeing eclipse references in the log since DDMS uses the eclipse base for the ui

Comment: Ah! That explains a lot with the Eclipse stuff in the log. I'll try updating later and see what happens. Hope to avoid the butt-pain of reinstalling the SDK...

Comment: Let me see if understand the project you are working on has at least one APL and your co worker does it in Eclipse and you from ant, correct? ADN the relative path to  the APL which is project.properties is different on your machine due to a difference in project layout, correct?